# Update apk file after changes to source - Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way I can just update the apk file after making changes to the android source file in eclipse. I want to be able to do this without actually pressing the Run button in eclipse.

The reason I want this is because - I usually keep the emulator open in the background (since booting it up everytime takes too much time on my slow computer). And when I run the program after a previous run, eclipse just seems to hang up - even after I have stopped the app in the emulator.

So I decided to use the adb install command-line program to install on the emulator, but am unable to get the apk file updated without actually pressing on the run button in eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, looks like mine only creates the APK if I run or Export, regardless of whether the Emulator is running the app or not. I wonder why your app hangs if you try to run from Eclipse? You could do a Build, then Export, and install the APK from the release folder.

Comment: I remember having the same problem, i suppose this is how it works [edit]: but I have no hang ups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the Eclipse ADT plugin works like you want it to work. Everybody just run emulator once and then pressing RUN button update the application. If you have problems with this post the logcat during the run of your application.

Comment: Yes, I realize that's how it should work. But it seems to hang up for me (possibly due to my antiquated computer)and basically freezes.

Comment: Try to see what happens in the logcat during the run. If you need help just post this logcat to us.

Answer (score 0):

You always can check the `Build Automatically` option in the Project menu option in Eclipse. Or you can `Project->Clean` your code, sometimes Eclipse get stuck trying to refresh all projects and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can un-install apk package with command line---- 
in linux os example:- `adb shell pm uninstall -k <package name>` 
You can leave -k if you don't want to delete data and cache.  If this command is failed then use emulator;
 open settings in emulator -> apps -> your app and then stop it or un-install with emulator and it is more easy. Options are depend on emulator device.